# How do I fix GA4 measurement protocol CORS preflight block for app served from Cloudfront via S3 bucket?

Tags: json, amazon-s3, cors, http-post, google-analytics-4

I am attempting to update UA to GA4. The app lives in an S3 bucket and is hosted on CloudFront.

Sending an analytics event works for me in Postman, where I have to set `Content-Type` to `application/json`.

However, the below does not work.

```
try {
        fetch(`https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=${measurementId}&api_secret=${apiSecret}`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
               "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                    client_id: client_id
                    events: [{
                        name: event,
                        params: params,
                    }]
                })
            });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

The error is a 405 -

```
Access to fetch at 'https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=<measurement id>&api_secret=<api secret>' from origin 'https://<cloudfront id>.cloudfront.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I've tried to set CORS in the s3 bucket with:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*.cloudfront.net"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

I've also tried to set the cloudfront url in the admin data stream cross-domain measurement from the Google Analytics 4 dashboard.

I understand that this has something to do with simple requests that don't accept application/json, only application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain. However, the Google Analytics 4 measurement protocol requires application/json.

**Question**:
How do I send GA4 analytics events from CloudFront/S3 to GA4 Measurement Protocol API with the required JSON without CORS policy block? Do I have to use a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot modify the headers on the Google Analytics server, one common approach is to set up a proxy server. The proxy server can forward requests to Google Analytics and add the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the responses.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).